# Suddenly misaligned navigation bar

Tags: css, alignment

The navigation bar (can be viewed [here](http://torbaybusroutes.co.uk)) has become misaligned in Google Chrome (latest version) without any change to the coding.

The large white space present between the two rows did not used to exist, nor did the further misalignment of the four far right links.

I am only of aware of this issue in Chrome - it displays correctly in Safari and Firefox.

### Code:

A code snippet for the navigation bar in the header.php is below:

```
<center>

<div class="navholder">
<div class="navigate">
<ul class="navigate">
<li class="navigate"><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../buses.php">Bus Routes</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../maps.php">Maps &amp; plans</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../news.php">News</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../myallocations.php">Enthusiasts</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../myroute/index.php">MyRoute</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../tbrtwitter.php">Live updates</a></li>
<li class="navigate"><a href="../tickets.php">Tickets</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>

<div class="navigateopposite">
<ul class="navigateopposite">
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../conpasses.php">Free travel</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../mobileservices.php">Mobile</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../operators.php">Operators</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../usingthebus.php">Using the bus</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../team.php">TBR Team</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../contact.php">Contact</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../advertise.php">Advertising</a></li>
<li class="navigateopposite"><a href="../about.php">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div></div>

</center>
```

### CSS:

The related CSS is also here:

```
/*Navigation bar*/
.navigate ul{float:left;width:1050px;margin-top:1px;text-align:center;}
.navigate ul li{display:inline;}
.navigate ul li a{width:127px;background:url(../images/navbar.gif)center center no-repeat;color: #000;text-decoration:none;float:left;text-align:center;line-height:50px;font-size:20px;vertical-align:top;margin: 0 1px 0 0;}
.navigate ul li a:hover{color: #fff;}
.navigate ul li a:active{color:#FFF;}

.navigateopposite ul{float:left;width:1050px;margin-top:1px;}
.navigateopposite ul li{display:inline;}
.navigateopposite ul li a{width:127px;background:url(../images/navbaropposite.gif)center center no-repeat;color: #000;text-decoration:none;float:left;text-align:center;line-height:50px;font-size:20px;vertical-align:top;margin: 0 1px 0 0;}
.navigateopposite ul li a:hover{color: #fff;}
.navigateopposite ul li a:active{color:#FFF;}
```

### Question:

What would be causing this strange misalignment?

Comment: FYI your link to jQuery is busted. http://torbaybusroutes.co.uk/js/jquery-1.8.0.min.js

Comment: Whoops - that was an old bit of unneeded code in the header file. Removed that now.

Comment: Sorry, more bad news. The validator found 46 errors. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ftorbaybusroutes.co.uk%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: All I know is that the navigation bar displayed correctly - then suddenly decided not to in Google Chrome, without any change to code

Comment: Well, fix the code and *then* deal with the (new) errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your CSS

```
li.navigate, li.navigateopposite {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
}
```

I added this through Chrome's developer tools and it seemed to remedy the problem.

This might fix it but seriously... as j08691 and David Thomas pointed out... that's some pretty crazy HTML you've got going on there. With nothing but good intentions, I hope you don't mind if I make a few comments?

1. You've got multiple `<head>`s in your document - you can only have one.
2. You're using `<div>` purely for layout purposes - if you need to add spaces in the layout you should be using pure CSS... HTML, as the name describes, is for markup only - not style information. By my reckoning you could lose at least half of that markup. As a generalisation, the more markup you have, the more difficulties you're going to get into like stuff apparently breaking randomly.
3. I can understand not wanting to support IE7 at a push, but *all* versions of IE?? ("Something not working? You're using Internet Explorer"). I know IE can be pretty hateful but you can't throw the book at 10% of all of your website visitors.

I hope this helps set you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer - that appears to have worked.

With regard to the coding, I'm afraid the development of this website was already at the absolute brink of my web development knowledge, and unless I seek professional help, I'm not going to be able to remedy the issues myself. I thank you for your suggestions, and please be assured I'm aware of these issues, and I would love to just be able to wave a magic wand at it all, but I can't see that happening right at this moment. Nevertheless, thank you for drawing this to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for taking the criticism how it was intended :) StackOverflow is populated by geeky, pro web developers (and I class myself in that group) who like to see everything "just so" :) Good luck with the rest of the project!

Comment: I've worked my way through the errors and have managed to correct the majority of them. The issues presented in IE have now all been fixed, so it seems to all be working much more smoothly. Thank you for drawing this to my attention again.